# RAID 1 on server - need file from mirrored drive

Tags: ubuntu, raid

About 3yrs back I had setup an Ubuntu server for a medical clinic.
I had set in 2 HDD's for the purpose of having RAID 1 (software RAID)[image: RAID setup]

Today suddenly they can't access a table on one of the mySQL database.

How now would it be possible to recover the mySQL database from the mirrored (backup) HDD?

Answer (score 5):

A mirror is just a protection against a single drive failure.  *It is not a replacement for a back-up.*  If the database is not accessible from the RAID-1, it will not be accessible from a single disk neither...

The only recourse is: copy the full database to 2 individual disks (to have 2 copies) using `ddrescue`, analyse the individual disk's SMART data with `smartctl` and `badblocks`, install new disks if needed, format the (new?) disks and restore the latest back-up and then extract the raw data on one of the copies and import as much data as can be imported from the extract.

You *will* have data loss, though with `ddrescue` it should be minimal and *hopefully* in the indexes only!

Answer (score 4):

RAID immediately copies changes to *both* disks. So if you, e.g., `rm` a file, it'll be `rm`'d on both disks. Or if something corrupts it, or whatever else.

RAID-1 only protects from a disk failing. If a disk fails, the array will continue to work with barely any interruption, just only using one less disk. There isn't really a 'primary' and 'backup' disk conceptually, two two (or more) disks function as one very reliable disk.

You can check the array status via, e.g., `cat /proc/mdstat`. If the array is OK, and you've experienced MySQL corruption, MySQL has recovery tools... other than that, restore from backup.

Comment: This!  RAID is a high availability solution, not a backup.

Answer (score 3):

There is no backup drive, if you have RAID-1, there is just a mirror. If one drive goes down (from a two drive array), you should  still be able access the second drive, and if that goes down (as seems to be your case), you have to restore from backup.

If the system is up you can check the status of the raid by doing:

```
cat /prod/mdstat
```

If you have one of the drives working you'll have an U in the output (between square brackets like `[U_]`) in that case your RAID is "only" degraded, but in that case it should still work. And I assume you had email notification setup for the RAID anyway.

You should check the drive status with `smartctl`.

Comment: it doesn't look like a HDD failure. Ubuntu boots up well and everything is running fine except that when the medical app starts (where the login works fine) it gives an error saying the table called patient_data is marked as corrupt and an auto repair failed

Answer (score 0):

I followed instructions at http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/
and got the table repaired.
App is now working fine.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You might wish to summarized what you've done. a link-only answer is hardly an answer.